# How do I make my for loop go to the end of the char* array and put every city in a linked list(The citys are divided by a whitespace)

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, linked-list, char

So in my homework I need to sort cities alphabetically by the first letter, if there are more citys with the same starting letter, then output them in the reverse order.

I have managed to get the the input from a file into the buffer char array.
But when I try to to sort it(go through the array it doesnt work)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class List
{
    struct Node
    {
        char* input;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:
    List()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    void createnode(char* city)
    {
        Node* temp = new Node;
        temp->input= city;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            Node* point = new Node;
            point->input= city;
            point->next = head;
            head = point;
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        Node* point = head;
        if (point == NULL)
        {
            cout << endl << "====================================" << endl << "List Doesnt exist/is deleted" << endl << "====================================" << endl;
            return;
        }
        cout << endl << "your list:" << endl;
        while (point != NULL)
        {
            cout << point->input<< "\t";
            point = point->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
  ////////////////THE PART WHERE I EXTRACT INFORMATION FROM THE INPUT FILE
    ifstream file("paldies.in", ifstream::binary);
    fstream file2;
    file2.open("paldies.out", ios::out);
    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Error desune!";
        return 0;
    }
    file.seekg(0, file.end);
    int length = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, file.beg);
    char * buffer = new char[length];
    cout << "Reading " << length << " characters....." << endl;
    file.read(buffer, length);

    if (length == 0)
    {
        char nothing[8] = "Nothing";
        file2.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(nothing), 8 * sizeof(char));
        file.close();
        file2.close();
        return 0;
    }

    if (file)
    {
        cout << "all characters read succesfully.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "error: only " << file.gcount() << " could be read";
    }
    file.close();

////////////////////////////THIS IS THE PART THATS NOT WORKING FOR ME

    List a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z;

    for (buffer; *buffer != '\0'; buffer++)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 's')
        {
        char s_begining[255] = "";

            for (int i = 0; buffer[0] != ' '; i++)
            {
                s_begining[i] = buffer[0];
                buffer++;
            }
            s.createnode(s_benining);
        }
        buffer++;
    }

cout << endl<<buffer<<endl;



    s.display();
    file2.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Input: springfield philadelphia detroit cleveland miami denver springfield seattle jacksonville

Correct output: cleveland denver detroit jacksonville miami philadelphia seattle springfield springfield

Actual output: since im just testing with the letter s it comes out as springfield only once, if I change the char s_begining declaration to outside of the if statement or the loop it gives different results.

I have a feeling that the problem is somewhere in the first for loop because when I take it out the first element goes into the list just fine, but when I put back in sometimes theres an exception, nothing happens(Empty list), or the list has 4 inputs with also garbage data in them.

Also if  I delete the buffer++; at the end of the first for loop it also breaks stuff.

So far I have gotten 1 city name in the list correctly and thats the first one (springfield).

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I am only allowed to use the fstream library, everything elese has to be coded by myself!

Comment: Good point to start learning how to use the debugger, and stepping through your code line by line. You can watch how variables are changing at each step, and see if there's something unexpected happening.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I guess youre right!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of what you’re trying to do can be achieved using the [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // 0. Set up variables
    std::ifstream inFile("pladies.in");
    std::ofstream outFile("pladies.out");
    std::vector<std::string> cities;

    // 1. Read each line of the input file to a vector
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inFile, line)) {
        cities.push_back(line);
    }

    // 2. Sort the vector alphabetically
    std::sort(cities.begin(), cities.end());

    // 3. Write the vector to the output file
    std::copy(cities.begin(), cities.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(outFile, "\n"));
}
```

([*repl.it*](https://repl.it/repls/StrikingLoathsomeBruteforceprogramming))